# Which DNS is for Linux

Tags: internet

Norton DNS protect form malicious websites but it's not specified that it protect the Linux aswell.
  Norton DNS is overkill since 99% of the malicious sites won't affect Linux users because they're focused on blocking sites with exploits for Windows.

Should I need some special DNS for Linux?

I need specific DNS for specific O.S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Norton uses these DNS:

> Security + Pornography
>
> - Preferred DNS: nameserver 198.153.192.50
> - Alternate DNS: nameserver 198.153.194.50
>
> Security (malware, phishing sites and scam sites)
>
> - Preferred DNS:  nameserver 198.153.192.40
> - Alternate DNS: nameserver 198.153.194.40
>
> Security + Pornography + Non-Family Friendly
>
> - Preferred DNS: nameserver 198.153.192.60
> - Alternate DNS: nameserver 198.153.194.60

The DNS in itself has nothing to do with the operating system you use. You can add these DNS to Linux using [systemd-resolv](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-resolved.service.html). Old answers might suggest to edit `/etc/resolve.conf` but that file will be overwritten. From the link:

> **/etc/resolv.conf**
>
> Four modes of handling `/etc/resolv.conf` (see [resolv.conf(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/resolv.conf.5.html)) are supported:
>
> **systemd-resolved** maintains the `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf` file for compatibility with traditional Linux programs. This file may be symlinked from `/etc/resolv.conf`. This file lists the 127.0.0.53 DNS stub (see above) as the only DNS server. It also contains a list of search domains that are in use by systemd-resolved. The list of search domains is always kept up-to-date. Note that `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf` should not be used directly by applications, but only through a symlink from `/etc/resolv.conf`. This file may be symlinked from `/etc/resolv.conf` in order to connect all local clients that bypass local DNS APIs to systemd-resolved with correct search domains settings. This mode of operation is recommended.
>
> A static file `/usr/lib/systemd/resolv.conf` is provided that lists the 127.0.0.53 DNS stub (see above) as only DNS server. This file may be symlinked from `/etc/resolv.conf` in order to connect all local clients that bypass local DNS APIs to systemd-resolved. This file does not contain any search domains.
>
> **systemd-resolved** maintains the `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` file for compatibility with traditional Linux programs. This file may be symlinked from `/etc/resolv.conf` and is always kept up-to-date, containing information about all known DNS servers. Note the file format's limitations: it does not know a concept of per-interface DNS servers and hence only contains system-wide DNS server definitions. Note that `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` should not be used directly by applications, but only through a symlink from `/etc/resolv.conf`. If this mode of operation is used local clients that bypass any local DNS API will also bypass systemd-resolved and will talk directly to the known DNS servers.
>
> Alternatively, `/etc/resolv.conf` may be managed by other packages, in which case systemd-resolved will read it for DNS configuration data. In this mode of operation systemd-resolved is consumer rather than provider of this configuration file.
>
> Note that the selected mode of operation for this file is detected fully automatically, depending on whether `/etc/resolv.conf` is a symlink to `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` or lists 127.0.0.53 as DNS server.

Pick any of the 4 methods to add the DNS listed at the top.